# Email Template Not Mapping Information from Web-to-Lead Form

Tags: javascript, email-template, salesforce-id, web2lead

I am a bit new to salesforce. I am trying to populate "Signed Date" from my Web form on to the email template. But it is not populating only that field.My email tepelate is:

Signed (Student) Date  {!Lead.FormFee_Student_Signed_Date__c}

The HTML that I am using in the form is:

```
<li class="form-line" id="id_62">
<label class="form-label-left" id="label_62" for="input_62"> Signed (Student ) Date </label>
 <div id="cid_62" class="form-input">
  <input type="text" class="today form-textbox" data-type="input-textbox" size="20" value=""/>
 <input class='today' type="hidden" id="00N90000009oR9b" name="00N90000009oR9b" size="20" value=""/> </div>
 </li>
```

The id that I am using for the signed date is for the custom field tat I have created in lead. One more thing, there is a Javascript in a form which is populating the current date in the Web form when the form gets opened.

Any suggestion will be highly valuable. Thanks in advance

Comment: I could not see in your code that you are using the field. Can you please check your code again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of populating the signed date from the webform, as it appears to be a hidden field.  Just populate the field upon creation of the lead.

In SFDC make the default for Signed date be "Today()".  So every time a person submits this form, your lead is created with a signed date as the current date.  From there your email will be populated.